# Running C++ SpiderMonkey on OSX produces Linker errors

Tags: javascript, c++, linker-errors, spidermonkey

I am trying to compile SpiderMonkey code on OSX, but Xcode keeps giving me Mach-O Linker errors.

In order to build, I follow the Mozilla instructions:

```
cd js/src
autoconf-2.13

mkdir build-release
cd build-release
../configure
make
```

I then do a:

```
make install
```

which puts the headers, a and dylib into my `/usr/local/` folders. In order to point `Xcode` to the headers, I have:

**Header Search Paths:**

```
/usr/local/include/**
```

**Library Search Paths:**

```
/usr/local/lib/**
```

I have checked to make sure the `libmozjs-24.dylib` and `libmozjs-24.a` exist in the respective `usr` folders. I dragged and dropped them into my XCode project.

**Linker Errors**

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "JS_ResolveStub(JSContext*, JS::Handle, JS::Handle)",
>   referenced from:
>         global_class in main.o   "JS_PropertyStub(JSContext*, JS::Handle, JS::Handle,
>   JS::MutableHandle)", referenced from:
>         global_class in main.o   "JS_DeletePropertyStub(JSContext*, JS::Handle, JS::Handle, int*)", referenced from:
>         global_class in main.o   "JS_StrictPropertyStub(JSContext*, JS::Handle, JS::Handle, int,
>   JS::MutableHandle)", referenced from:
>         global_class in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

I am trying to follow the following "hello world"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_User_Guide

and my code is as follows:

```
#define JS_DEBUG 1

/* Include the JSAPI header file to get access to SpiderMonkey. */
#include <jsapi.h>

static JSClass global_class = { "global",
    JSCLASS_NEW_RESOLVE | JSCLASS_GLOBAL_FLAGS,
    JS_PropertyStub,
    JS_DeletePropertyStub,
    JS_PropertyStub,
    JS_StrictPropertyStub,
    JS_EnumerateStub,
    JS_ResolveStub,
    JS_ConvertStub,
    nullptr,
    JSCLASS_NO_OPTIONAL_MEMBERS
};

int run(JSContext *cx) {

    JSAutoRequest ar(cx);

    JSObject *global = JS_NewGlobalObject(cx, &global_class, nullptr);
    if (!global)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    JSRuntime * runtime;

    runtime = JS_NewRuntime(8L * 1024L * 1024L, JS_NO_HELPER_THREADS);
    if (runtime == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot create runtime");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Create a context. */
    JSContext *cx = JS_NewContext(runtime, 8192);
    if (!cx)
        return 1;
    JS_SetOptions(cx, JSOPTION_VAROBJFIX);
    //JS_SetErrorReporter(cx, reportError);

    int result = run(cx);

    JS_DestroyContext(cx);
    JS_DestroyRuntime(runtime);

    /* Shut down the JS engine. */
    JS_ShutDown();

    return result;
}
```

It seems part of the code has no issues with linking, but others do.

Any hope is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I ran the same code using GCC through the terminal using:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include /usr/local/lib/libmozjs-24.a -lm -ldl main.cpp -o main
```

I get an output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "JS_ResolveStub(JSContext*, JS::Handle<JSObject*>, JS::Handle<jsid>)", referenced from:
      global_class in main-fa83e1.o
  "JS_PropertyStub(JSContext*, JS::Handle<JSObject*>, JS::Handle<jsid>,     JS::MutableHandle<JS::Value>)", referenced from:
      global_class in main-fa83e1.o
  "JS_DeletePropertyStub(JSContext*, JS::Handle<JSObject*>, JS::Handle<jsid>, int*)", referenced from:
      global_class in main-fa83e1.o
  "JS_StrictPropertyStub(JSContext*, JS::Handle<JSObject*>, JS::Handle<jsid>, int,     JS::MutableHandle<JS::Value>)", referenced from:
  global_class in main-fa83e1.o
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a more [modern how-to guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/How_to_embed_the_JavaScript_engine) available that demonstrates the fix for your issue: don't specify the Stubs anymore. Your global class can become:

```
static JSClass global_class = {
    "global",
    JSCLASS_GLOBAL_FLAGS
};
```

and your runtime creation can become:

```
runtime = JS_NewRuntime(8L * 1024L * 1024L);
```

and it should at least compile.